# Airflow task in up_for_reschedule status but does not release worker

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG with an `HttpSensor` set to `mode="reschedule"`. This task is hitting an API that will return `True` after 100 seconds for a specified run. I thought that setting my sensor to `mode="reschedule"` would free the worker so that it could pick up a new task or start working on a new run. This does not seem to be the case, as I can have 16 parallel Runs whether they are in `up_for_reschedule` or `running` status.

Am I misunderstanding what `mode="reschedule"` does?

Or is there a limit to the number of concurrent runs I can have set elsewhere? If so, is there a way to set the number of workers (so as to not run out of resources) but have an unlimited number of runs?

The rescheduled task:

```
    wait_for_sleep = HttpSensor(
        task_id='http_sensor_check',
        http_conn_id='',
        endpoint="http://0.0.0.0:8081/long_sleep/{{run_id}}",
        request_params={},
        response_check=lambda response: response.text == "True",
        poke_interval=60,
        dag=dag,
        mode='reschedule',
    )
```

[image: 16 up_for_reschedule tasks]

[image: 16 running tasks]

I also scaled up the number of concurrent runs a DAG could have, so that it exceeded the number of `max_active_tasks_per_dag`. Thinking this would mean 16 tasks in the `running` state and an unlimited number in the `up_for_reschedule` state. However, it looks like that is not the case.

[image: number of active tasks blocked by up_for_reschedule tasks]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? What scheduler are you using?

Comment: @Ethan, i did not I just bailed on airflow and am now using AWS Step Functions, which is a better fit for my needs anyway.